# Unix Copy Recursive Including All Directories

Tags: unix

I have the following two directories:

```
~/A
    drawable/
        imageb.png
    new/`
        newimage.png

~/B
    drawable/
        imagec.png
```

When I use the `cp -r ~/A/* ~/B` command newimage.png with its new/ folder is copied across to ~/B however imageb.png is not copied into ~/B/drawable.

Could you explain why this is the case and how I can get around this?

Comment: Are you on UNIX or did you mean Linux? Are these regular files or links?

Comment: It's probably not directly causing your problem, but I would use `cp -r ~/A ~/B`, leaving out the `*`.  What happens if you try copying to a nonexistent directory, for example with `cp -r ~/A ~/new_B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tar instead of cp:

```
(cd A ; tar cf - *) | (cd B ; tar xf -)
```

or more compactly (if you're using GNU tar):

```
tar cC A -f - . | tar xC B -f -
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on linux you can use the `-r` option.

eg: `cp -r ~/A/. ~/B/`

If you are on BSD you could use the `-R` option.

eg: `cp -R ~/A/. ~/B/`

For more information on exactly what option you should pass, refer `man cp`

Also note that, if you do not have permissions to the file you it would prevent copying files.